# Magazine Manager drag and drop not working?

Tags: drag-and-drop

A coworker came over to ask me about [The Magazine Manager](http://www.magazinemanager.com/intranet/aspNET/PublicSite/Default.aspx) today at work.  She was attempting to drag and drop some list items from one pane to another within the Webapp, but without any success.  She's running  in Internet Explorer on Windows 7 64-bit and Internet Explorer 9 32-bit.

[image: My Co-Workers Version of IE9]

I tried it on my machine with Internet Explorer 9 64-bit and I didn't have any problem dragging and dropping the items.  I am also running IE9 on Windows 7.

[image: My version of IE9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out it had something to do with Compatibility Mode, and that drag and drop will work if you use it; However if you turn on Compatibility Mode on, it breaks something else, so you just have to tweek that based on what you are working with.

Also I'm told pressing the esc key will fix it for some reason...can anyone verify this?